# Tracking Facebook Ad Users

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

So we use Facebook Ads for Mobile to get users for our iOS app.

I've been looking through the documentation and I can't seem to find a way to know WHEN the user who has come into the app is a facebook user. Facebook can send app insights and I assume that means that somehow the SDK knows if the user is a converted Facebook user or not.

Is there any native API call that I can use to determine if the user is in fact a facebook app install?

I would also be cool if there was a third party service that did as long as it is reported INSIDE the app wether they were from Facebook or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

32  {'action.type': 'mobile_app_install', 'application':APPLICATION_ID} Number of times users install the app through a mobile app install ad if there is an iOS/Android version

check this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/tracking-specs/

Suprising I did not think apple would allow facebook to access information that would also facebook to know whether the user actually installed the app or not as It just redirect's the user to the app in the app store.

Comment: I believe this gets you the data on the Facebook side of things. Which we have, I was wondering if there was an iOS app client side way of knowing which user is a Facebook app installed user.